# Error when using a custom template tag - object does not support item assignment

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create my own templatetag. How I've done this:

folder structure:

```
my_app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    my_app/
        templates/
            show.html
    templatetags/
            __init__.py
            depos.py
```

depos.py:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django import template
from core.models import Depos

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('show.html')
def show_dep():
    dep = Depos.objects.all().order_by('?')[0]
    return dep
```

show.html:

```
<div id="user_testimonial">
    <blockquote>
        <p>{{ dep.dep }}</p>
        <cite>{{ dep.name }}, {{ dep.from }}</cite>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

in my templates:

```
{% load depos %}
{% show_dep %}
```

but I've got this error:

```
TypeError at /cadastro  
'Depos' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be passing a dictionary object from your inclusion tag to your inclusion tag template. [It's mentioned in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags):

> First, define the function that takes the argument and produces a dictionary of data for the result. The important point here is we only need to return a dictionary, not anything more complex.

so try:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('show.html')
def show_dep():
    return {
        'dep' : Depos.objects.all().order_by('?')[0]
    }
```